# Reducing raster legend classes to the ones shown in my map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, land-cover, qml

I have a landcover raster layer. I use the styles of a QML-file. Is there an option to reduce my style classes shown in the legend to only the relevant classes shown in the map?

The QML has 44 classes, but on the map, there are only 26 classes shown. In ArcGIS, there was an option to automatically reduce the legend to the relevant classes. Is that also possible in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: It's not the solution you want, but it is easy to select multiple classes in the layer's symbology using the windows selection methods (shift or alt key + select) and delete them from that symbology, and then they won't show in the inserted legend.

Comment: Yes, that is what I normally do with other datasets. But in this case I have to verify for each class whether they are actually shown in the map. This is ok, if I do it once. But this approach doesn't work when I use the Atlas function and each region has a different combination of landcover classes...

Comment: Have you tried ticking the checkbox to "Only show items inside linked map" ("Nur Objekte innerhalb der verknüpften Karte anzeigen" in your attached image) ?

Comment: I think the" only items inside option" works with vector layers but that does suggest another workaround - convert the raster to polygons and then use that in the maps.

Comment: @BenW: Yes I tried that, the result is the same.

Comment: @johns: Good idea! Yes, that would work for that specific map. It would not work for the atlas function and for a bigger country like Germany, because the resulting vector-layer file size would be too large and therefore too slow to process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just need to push the button "classify" in the style settings in the layer settings, after I imported the QML-file. Then it reduces the 44 clc classes to the actual existing 25 clc classes in the region.

In the screenshot, you can see that clc classes not existing in the region (like the ocean, lagunes, etc.) are not shown in the legend anymore.

[image]

[image]

[image]